# How to expose my teamsite to internet

Tags: alternate-access-mapping, internet-sites

I have a teamsite which I want to expose to internet for my team managers to see. I have External IP and Port which my IT manager has mapped it to my machines IP. Now I have the site on my machine.

Comment: I think you have to configure the router / modem for the port forwarding and then map, because for example if you are inside the same network, your manager can connect by ip:port of your computer to sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

Define [Alternate Access Mappings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff679917.aspx) from Central Admin for your teamsite

Open Central Administration -> Application Management -> Configure Alternate Access Mappings -> Add Internal URLs [Select Internet in Zone and make sure to select Web Application]

Comment: I have added external ip with port number in IIS bindings and in Alternate access mappings but after that although I can access my site externally but the links on the site for example the "Add new Item" link button is not working. And when I am checking where its pointing to, it shows me only external ip address and not the port number

Comment: ok.. so you mean that I should add the external ip to AAM and not in IIS bindings

Comment: Im typing http://203.18.210.22:888/default.aspx then it shows me the site page externally but the links on the site have http://203.18.210.22 only not the port number ?

Comment: Just write `http://203.18.210.22:888`

Comment: http://203.18.210.22:888 is taking me to http://203.18.210.22/default.aspx and fiddler shows this message "ErrorCode: 10061. 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 203.18.210.22:80 "

Comment: have added you to my skype

Comment: Updated the answer, try that! And `http://203.18.210.22:888` in Add Internal URL.. Can't connect to skype right now!

Comment: No, still not solved